# how can i stop pass by reference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pass-by-reference

i have a problem with passing by reference or value.

and i know people might thing this is a duplicate post but i did not find a way to solve this.

I have something like:

```
//<div data-content="{bigObject}" id="SomeId"></div>

   // Originally bigObject was something like:

bigObject = {
    place : 'home',
    time : ''
};

$('#SomeId').click(function(){
    $(this).someFunction();
});

(function($){
    $.fn.someFunction = function(){
        var m = {
            obj : this,
            bigObject : '',
            initialize : function(){
                m.bigObject = m.obj.data('content');
                m.manipulateObject();
            },
            manipulateObject : function(){
                m.bigObject.place = 'work';
            }
        }
        m.initialize();
        return m.obj;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The issue is when i click on `SomeId` the big object changes both in the div's `data('content')` and in the function `m.bigObject.place`

Is there a way to not change them both ?

Comment: Just store the object somewhere else ?

Comment: like where ? its seems no matter where i stored it. it kept passing by ref..

Comment: Oh, I see, you need to do `var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, oldObject);`

Comment: I tried to pass it not by reference i tried doing bigObject.clone() and it throw and error

Comment: You can't clone an object, but you can use $.extend to create a new object containing the exact same data.

Comment: ah that might work !! so you're `var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, oldObject);` will basically create a new object in newObject.. nice i will try that

Comment: Indeed it will, and depending on wether or not you need a deep copy, you might have to do `var newbigObject = $.extend(true, {}, oldbigObject);`

Comment: Thanks adeneo very much i will look into that now and see

Comment: JavaScript has only pass-by-value, just like Java. There is no pass by reference.

Comment: If there's only pass by reference how does the original objects changes when i preform something on item i equaled it to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new copy of the object and use that. You can use [jquery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) for that.

```
var newObject = $.extend({}, m.bigObject);
```

Instead of doing

```
manipulateObject : function(){
    m.bigObject.place = 'work';
}
```

You can do:

```
manipulateObject : function(object){
    object.place = 'work';
}
```

Comment: nah what i will do is just instead of `m.bigObject = m.obj.data('content');` i will clone the object and then use it.